# HTTPS authentication setup using camel-http?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to call https Rest API URL using Apache Camel API. **Is this possible to call https Rest API URL using with Apache Camel API without hard code the user name and password of the https URL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel allows to read properties from files. Camel uses the `{{key}}` syntax to refer to a property:

```
 from("direct:start")
     .to("https://<your-url>?authMethod=Basic&authUsername={{username}}&authPassword={{password}}");
```

In this example, the properties `username` and `password` are defined in a property file that can be initialized as follows:

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:com/mycompany/myprop.properties");
context.addComponent("properties", pc);
```

More information can be found at http://camel.apache.org/properties.html.